# create element not appear in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to create svg and add to children list's parent, but nothing's appear but if I put this code directly in HTML just the tag this is working can someone tell me why please

```
function    setAttributes(node, attributes){
    for (attribut in attributes){
        node.setAttribute(attribut, attributes[attribut]);
    }
}

function    createIconToParent(parentNode, error){
    let svgTag = document.createElement('svg');
    let pathTag = document.createElement ('path');

    setAttributes(svgTag, { "aria-hidden"   :   "true",
                            "focusable"     :   "false",
                            "data-prefix"   :   "fas",                           
                            "role"          :   "img",
                            "xmlns"         :   "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                            "viewBox"       :   "0 0 512 512"
                        });

    if (error == true){
        setAttributes(svgTag, { "data-icon" :   "exclamation-circle",
                                "class"     :   "svg-inline--fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-w-16"
                            });
        setAttributes(pathTag, { "fill" :   "#08c708",
                                    "d" :   "M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314\
                                            387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216\
                                            308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0\
                                            22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"});
    }
    else{
        setAttributes(svgTag, { "data-icon" :   "check-circle",
                                "class"     :   "svg-inline--fa fa-check-circle fa-w-16"
                            });
        setAttributes(pathTag, {"fill"  :   "crimson",
                                    "d" :   "M504 256c0 136.997-111.043 248-248 248S8 392.997 8 256C8 119.083 119.043 8 256 8s248\
                                            111.083 248 248zm-248 50c-25.405 0-46 20.595-46 46s20.595 46 46 46 46-20.595\
                                            46-46-20.595-46-46-46zm-43.673-165.346l7.418 136c.347 6.364 5.609 11.346 11.982 11.346h48.546c6.373 0\
                                            11.635-4.982 11.982-11.346l7.418-136c.375-6.874-5.098-12.654-11.982-12.654h-63.383c-6.884 0-12.356\
                                            5.78-11.981 12.654z"});
    }

    svgTag.appendChild(pathTag);
    parentNode.appendChild(svgTag);
}
createIconToParent(document.body, true);
```

Comment: You can't use document.createElement for SVG. You need to use document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg') and document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is non-standard to HTML. HTML can contain SVG, but SVG can not contain HTML. For that reason, javascript uses `document.createElementNS` instead of `document.createElement` for the creation of SVG elements within HTML code.

What you need to do in order to get your code to work is this:

```
function    createIconToParent(parentNode, error){
    let svgTag = document.createElementNS('w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    let pathTag = document.createElementNS('w3.org/2000/svg','path');

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you a for you explanations and your solution !